# How to Navigate to another Page After running an Animation

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Basically I have a couple of buttons on a page, when a user clicks one of the buttons the application has to run an animation then navigate to a second page with the name of the button stored in the query string

```
 private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            myAnimation.Begin();
            myAnimation.Completed += new EventHandler(myAnimation_Completed);

        }

        void myAnimation_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             //If Button1 was clicked
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/nextPage.xaml?id=Button1",UriKind.Relative));

             //If Button2 was clicked
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/nextPage.xaml?id=Button2",UriKind.Relative));

             //etc
        }
```

I don't know what condition I can use for the IF statements.

EDIT: Managed to solve the navigation problem by changing the event statement to

```
myAnimation.Completed += new EventHandler((a,b) => MyAnimation_complete(sender, e));
```

but now am having trouble navigating back, when I click the back button from the second page I go to the first page but I find no controls there.It may also be helpful to note the "MyAnimation" is just a transition animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't use lambda expressions

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myAnimation.Begin();
        myAnimation.Completed += (s,ev)=>
          {
           NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/nextPage.xaml?id=Button1",UriKind.Relative));
          };

    }
```

samething for Button2

Comment: Why does navigating in this manner make it impossible to navigate back to the previous page using the back button?

Comment: I think its better to create an instance of next page  & see if it works, so `NavigationService.Navigate(new nextPage(Button1));`,

Comment: Using lambda expressions works perfectly!, I was not able to get back to the previous page because my animation moved all controls out of the page.

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

> myAnimation.Completed += new EventHandler((sender, e) =>
>   MyAnimation_complete(sender, e);

In this way, you can get your infromation from your e variable, and handle your buttons this way.

Comment: Thanks! Works when I change the first "( sender, e)" to random variable names like ( a, b ). I.E myAnimation.Completed += new EventHandler((a,b) => MyAnimation_complete(sender, e));

Comment: @KillaKem if this works Please mark it as answer, so it may be useful to others

Answer (score 1):

Just create bool variable which is set to true if Button 1 is clicked and to false when button 2 (or some int if You have more buttons)

Comment: But then I would have to make the int a global variables :( Is there really no other way? I hate having global variables in my code.

Comment: @KillaKem, it is not global variable but just a private member of class - using them is not against any OOP rule.